# Convert Boolean expression to django queryset

Tags: django, tagging, boolean-logic

I have tagging in place on my django site, and I'd like to allow urls of the form:

```
http://example.com/search/tags/(foo+dog)|(goat+cat)
```

Which in English would mean:

> Find the items tagged with (foo AND dog) OR (goat AND cat).

So essentially what I need is a way to pare this down into queries using the Django API. At present, I just want to support AND, OR and parentheses.

I imagine there are libraries for interpreting Booleans of this sort, but I haven't been able to find any outside of a full-blown search engine. Are there any tricks to doing this or good starting points using the Django API?

Right now, my code is pretty basic, but it supports **either** OR queries **or** AND queries, but not them combined (thus no parentheses either).

**EDIT**:
I'm fairly convinced that if I could sort this out into a series of AND and OR queries, I'd be all set...but I can't think through how to go from the randomly parenthesised boolean query to a logically useful understanding of the query.

Here's the code I have so far, in case it's useful. I'm not using the tagging module (though maybe I should), and the code is still drafty, but...

```
@login_required
def view_opinions_by_tag(request, tagValues):
    '''Displays opinions tagged by a user with certain tags.

    Given a set of tags separated by pluses, pipes, and parentheses, unpack
    the set of tags and display the correct opinions. Currently only supports
    pluses (AND filters), and pipes (OR filters).
    '''
    if '|' in tagValues:
        # it's an or query.
        tagList = tagValues.split('|')
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(tag__in = tagList, user = request.user)\
            .values_list('pk', flat=True)
        faves = Favorite.objects.filter(tags__in = list(tags), user = request.user).distinct()

    elif '+' in tagValues:
        # it's an and query - not very efficient.
        tagList = tagValues.split('+')
        tagObject = Tag.objects.get(tag = tagList[0], user = request.user)
        faves = Favorite.objects.filter(tags = tagObject, user = request.user)
        for tag in tagList[1:]:
            tagObject = Tag.objects.filter(tag = tag, user = request.user)
            faves = faves.filter(tags = tagObject, user = request.user).distinct()

    else:
        # it's a single tag
        tag = Tag.objects.get(tag = tagValues, user = request.user)
        faves = Favorite.objects.filter(tags = tag, user = request.user)
```

From here, I essentially take the faves queryset, and render it. Perhaps not the most efficient, but seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

For the parsing, just set a regexp in your urls.py that will get you the stuff that you need:

```
url(r'^/search/tags/(?p<query>[a-z\-\+\|])$')
```

In your views:

```
def your_view(request, query):
    for and_exp in query.split('|'):
        for tag in and_exp.split('+'):
            # do your stuff with q object
```

*EDIT*:

Actually this is a generic answer, but I just realized that you are talking about tags, and therefor a many to many relation.

It will depends very much of the implementation so **you must give us more details.**

If you use [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/), you can make several queries using `Object.tagged.with_all('tag1', 'tag2')`

It's different for [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?redir), and different if you are using your own implementation.

Comment: I've added more details above. Hopefully enough to make it make sense.